# Body Background Image Clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I searched for hours trying to find a solution for creating a body background image clickable.

I managed to find some similar questions/answers here on stackoverflow but I don't know how to apply them.

So far I think that the code below might help but I cannot seem to understand how to use it on my website.

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    if (e.target === this) {
        window.location = "link.html"
    }
});
```

Can someone please explain how can I have this working on 007soccerpicks.com? I need the body background image clickable except for the `<div id="container">` which is the content area of the website.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you have setup will click the entire document if wrapped inside the body element. One way to get around this is to use a fixed element in the background with the body logic in another wrapper.

```
<body>
<div class="body-clickable"></div>
<div class="main-content">
</div>
</body>

<style>
.body-clickable 
{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-image: url('image.png');
}
.main-content {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1000px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
</style>

<script>
$('.body-clickable').click(function(e){
    if (e.target === this) {
        window.location = "link.html"
    }
});
</script>
```

You could also avoid using a script and actually just make the 'body-clickable' a link.

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you very much for this! I managed to do it with the code provided by you and replaced the script with a simple "a href". You're a lifesaver!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#box-link { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 8px; 
  left: 20px; 
  width: 83px; 
  height: 83px; 
  background-color: transparent; 
  border: 1px solid yellow; } 
.box1 { 
  position: relative; 
  margin: 20px 0 20px 40px; 
  padding: 5px 0; width: 300px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Y8Qx-xfqufE/VOIccUtbhpI/AAAAAAAABDI/x5lTXX_Zlrs/s2048/cool-and-stylish-girls-wallpapers-for-fb-cool-and-stylish-girls-with-guitar-6413-sadredheartlovequotesforfacebooktimelinecoverx.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box1">
  <a id="box-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
  <p>The background of this box is an image.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```